# If statement using numbers and && is not working. C#

Tags: c#, if-statement

I wrote this and it is not working, any ideas where I have gone wrong? And yes I am new to programming. Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

```
if ((int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()) < 10) && (int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()) > 0))
    Console.WriteLine("The right number!!");
else
    Console.WriteLine("The wrong number!!");

Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: What happens , any error or something?

Comment: Do you get any error messages? and what is in the surrounding braces?

Comment: @NikolaSmiljanić: That is a terrible code edit! No need to confuse the OP more than they already are

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It isn't working as you would expect because the way the if statement is written is expecting 2 lines of text to be read in from the console (as you've used Console.ReadLine()) twice.

You should be first assigning the input value to a variable

Which can then be used twice in the if statement as below:

```
    int inputNumber = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

if(inputNumber < 10 && inputNumber > 0)
{
    Console.WriteLine("The right number!!");
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("The wrong number!!");
}
```

Comment: Hey thanks, that is totally the problem. Cheers for letting me know.

Answer (score 3):

If you only want to read 1 input then try this:

```
int number = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

if (number > 0 && number < 10) {
    Console.WriteLine("The right number!!");
} else {
    Console.WriteLine("The wrong number!!");
}

Console.ReadLine();
```

This is because in your example both times you `Console.ReadLine()`, your code is asking for an input.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you do it this way:

```
var input = Console.ReadLine();
int number;

if (int.TryParse(input, out number))
{
    if (number > 0 && number < 10)
        Console.WriteLine("The right number!!");
    else
        Console.WriteLine("The wrong number!!");
}
```

Used `int.TryParse` in `if` statement to ensure the entering after getting the correct integer input.

Comment: Not sure there actually is two numbers...

Comment: I agree with musefan; I think Gilo actually wants to read a single input. Maybe.

Comment: Yea this seems to be the case. Anywaz i have edited it.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. I was originally writing a similar code of: int aNumber = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()); follow by the If statement If ((aNumber < 10) && (aNumber > 0))

Comment: Strange for having a downvote :)